# C++ multithread joining only working on the first thread but not working for other threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, threadpool

I was curious as to why the code below works and executes fine for the `n = 1` case, but when I make `n` anything greater than `1` I get a system error most of the time.

I also know there is `joinable()` for checking if a thread is done but it is terrible since it blocks the main thread. If there is a more elegant solution to checking when a thread is done than passing a boolean pointer to a method, that would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <array>

void my_function(bool* is_thread_done) {
    std::cout << "Thread started" << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    std::cout << "Thread finished" << std::endl;
    *is_thread_done = true;
}

int main() {   
    const int n = 1;
    std::array<std::thread, n> arr;
    std::array<bool, n> is_thread_done;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        is_thread_done[i] = false;
        arr[i] = std::thread(my_function, &is_thread_done[i]);
    }
    
    int all_done = 0;
    while (all_done < n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (is_thread_done[i]) {
                arr[i].join();
                all_done++;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have tried joinable but that is not useful because of blocking.

To answer the comments:

1. The order that I join the threads doesn't matter, but a loop is just the way I'm doing it.
2. I cannot join the thread before its done because it will block the main thread. I simplified this code from my actual use for it and I cannot have the main thread be blocked. This is the general premise though. That is why I also cannot use `joinable()` to join.
3. I have tried `atomic<bool>` and it did not seem to have any effect. I don't know why this would matter though however since by the time the boolean becomes set to `true`, the thread would be done.

Here is the code form the thread pool I was making. `n` threads working on some task k times. Since `k` is greater than `n`, when a thread finishes, a new thread is dispatched to continue working on the task. The main thread needs to dispatch another thread immediately, not wait for `n` thread to finish and then dispatch another thread. In that case its acting like a barrier which I don't need.

```
template<typename Func, typename... Args>
void ThreadPool::thread_pool_executor(Func func, Args... args) {
    while (running) {
        while (free_indecies.size() > 0 && running) {
            int i = free_indecies.front();
            pool[i] = std::make_unique<std::thread>(
                &ThreadPool::worker<Func, Args...>, this,
                &avalability[i], func, args...);
            free_indecies.pop();
            avalability[i] = false;
            current_iter++;
            if (current_iter == total_iter) running = false;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < max_threads; i++) {
            if (avalability[i]) {
                pool[i]->join();
                free_indecies.push(i);
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < max_threads; i++) {
        if (pool[i]->joinable()) {
            pool[i]->join();
        }
    }
    reset();
}

template<typename Func, typename... Args>
void ThreadPool::worker(std::atomic<bool>* complete, Func func, Args... args) {
    std::invoke(func, args...);
    *complete = true;
}
```

I realized what Ben was saying and changed the loop in the first code segment to the following and now that simpler example works. I created a set and initialized it to hold the numbers 1-n initially.

```
while (not_done.size() > 0) {
    for (int i : not_done) {
        if (is_thread_done[i]) {
            arr[i].join();
            not_done.erase(i);
        }
    }
}
```

I also realized that in the threadpool example where I am trying to apply this idea, I should have had `availability[i] = false` right before I make the thread to avoid a race condition. However the code from that case still has the `thread::join failed: Invalid argument Abort trap: 6` error

Comment: why don't you just join all the threads in any order? it doesn't matter what the order is? the thread doesn't have to have finished before you join it?

Comment: Your `while -> for` just keeps re-joining threads over and over again. Whats the point of all that? Just loop over all threads and `join`. Checking whether they are done is unnecessary, `join` _blocks_ until the thread is done.

Comment: how did you build? Not linking `pthread` can have strange effects, including sometimes working but other times crashign at runtime

Comment: `if (is_thread_done[i]) {` in the main thread and `*is_thread_done = true;`  in the other threads is a data race

Comment: You're using a plain `array<bool>`, not something like `atomic<bool>`. The compiler is free to assume no other thread touches that array between iterations.

Comment: comments are best *answered* by editing the question

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Concurrently modifying a `bool` is not a data race. It's only inconvenient because thread sanitizers will report it as such but there's no intermediate/unfinished state for the bool to be in, the modification is by nature "atomic". There are differences like the lack of memory fences and non guaranteed ordering but that is not a data race

Comment: This `is_thread_done` feature you've added is entirely unnecessary.  Just `join` the thread before doing anything that requires the thread to be done.

Comment: @LorahAttkins: As far as C++ cares (§[intro.races]/2): "Two expression evaluations *conflict* if one of them modifies a memory location (6.7.1) and the other one reads or modifies the same memory location."  and (§[intro.races]/21.2): "The execution of a program contains a data race if it contains two potentially concurrent conflicting actions, at least one of which is not atomic, [...]". I don't see anything making an exception for `bool`, so yes, it would appear that the OP does have a data race as the term is defined in C++.

Comment: When you say "_I cannot join the thread before its done because it will block the main thread_",  why not?  What exactly would you like the main thread to be doing while the other threads are doing their work?  Your example suggests that you would like to have the main thread wait (i.e. block) until all the other threads have finished.  Is that not what you want?

Comment: The `threadpool` tag seems irrelevant.  You are not making use of (or reusing a thread from) a pool of threads.  I think you intended to use the `multithreading` tag.

Comment: Currently when one thread finishes, you count it `n` times and exit.  That's why your other threads never get joined.

Comment: Re: "`joinable()` ... blocks the main thread" -- no, it doesn't block anything. But that doesn't mean it's useful here.

Comment: @LorahAttkins -- the modification is not "atomic" unless there's a lot more going on among the processors than is usual. Yes, there's probably no tearing of the value, which is what makes an operation atomic from the processor's perspective. But there's more to atomicity in C++ than that. There are also requirements about visibility in different processor caches and about reordering of instructions around atomic operations. That's why the C++ language goes into so much detail about what constitutes a data race, and that's why thread sanitizers are correct in complaining about updates to bools.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I can't argue with the Standard, I'll make sure to study the section on races. at PeteBecker Was aware of the ordering/memory fences differences (I mention them after all) but the way you tie it to what the languages considers proper atomic behavior makes sense, thanks for going into detail

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`std::async`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) to create a thread that is bound to a [`std::future`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future). Then you can call [`wait_for()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait_for) with `0` to check if it is done without blocking.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <array>

void my_function() {
    std::cout << "Thread started\n";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    std::cout << "Thread finished\n";
}

int main() {
    using namespace std::literals;

    const int n = 10;
    std::array<std::future<void>, n> arr;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i] = std::async(std::launch::async, my_function);
    }

    while (true) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            arr[i].wait_for(0s); // non-blocking
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be a few misconceptions here.

`joinable` doesn't block (at least for any significant amount of time), but it also doesn't tell you whether a thread has finished. It tells you whether a thread has *started* executing. If it has started executing, you need to join the thread before you destroy the thread object, or you get undefined behavior. So `joinable` won't (a least normally) block for any significant length of time.

`join()` will block, but in this case that doesn't seem to be a problem. Once you've fired the work off to the other threads, the only thing `main` has left to do (at least in the current code) is wait for the other threads to finish. So for this code as it stands now, we can write code on this general order:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <array>

void my_function(int i) {
    std::cout << "Thread " << i << " started\n";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    std::cout << "Thread " << i<< " finished\n";
}

int main() {   
    const int n = 10;
    std::array<std::thread, n> arr;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i] = std::thread(my_function, i);
    }

    // you might want to do something more intelligent here, such as if
    // you have a thread that's not joinable yet, sleep a while to get it
    // a chance to start running.
    for (auto & t : arr) {
        if (t.joinable())
            t.join();
    }    
}
```

I've added a bit to pass the index to each thread, so when it prints out its messages, it can identify itself.

Note that since we don't synchonize access to `cout`, this can/will routinely interleave output from different threads, so don't be surprised to get output something like this:

```
Thread 0 started
Thread 3 started
Thread 2 started
Thread Thread 4 started
1 started
Thread 5 started
Thread 6 started
Thread 7 started
Thread 8 started
Thread 9 started
Thread 3 finished
Thread 0 finished
Thread 2 finished
Thread 8 finished
Thread Thread 9 finished
Thread 7 finished
Thread 6 finished
1Thread 5 finished
 finished
Thread 4 finished
```

There are ways we could deal with that as well, but that's a separate question.

Comment: `joinable` or "active thread of execution" doesn't mean "started running". It means "non default constructed" or [get_id() != std::thread::id()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/joinable) (and "not previously joined of course")). If the former was the case `jthread` could trigger undefined behavior on destructor since they have identical requirements on `joinable`. As a result `if (t.joinable())` (or `while (!t.joinable())`) is not needed. To the best of my knowledge that is - after the `bool` incident on the OP's comments I'm questioning a lot of stuff

Comment: @LorahAttkins: Officially, it's strictly `get_id() != id()` (even if previously joined). But basically, that means it's started running (an OS thread has been allocated to run it).

Answer (score 0):

Join will anyways block until a thread has finished its work. So you don't have to explicitly check a finished status. If you also use a `jthread` you don't even have to manually `join`:

```cpp
void my_function() {
    std::cout << "Thread started" << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    std::cout << "Thread finished" << std::endl;
}

int main() {   
    const int n = 3;
    std::array<std::jthread, n> arr;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i] = std::jthread(my_function);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/abc1410929d5e363)

---

**tl;dr** (a couple more "copious" approaches follow)

You may want to decouple checking for completion from joining:

```
const auto done = [&is_thread_done]<size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>){
    return n == (std::get<Is>(is_thread_done) + ...);
};
    
while (!done(std::make_index_sequence<n>{})) { 
    std::this_thread::yield(); // Allow other threads to run.
}
    
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    arr[i].join();
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef89ced2a3fe0ebc)

In such a scenario you can even use a `jthread` and skip the explicit `.join` altogether [Demo2](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/34c4fad9f0726bad)

As shown in the demo, use `std::atomic` for your flags, the comments in your post describe why that is the proper course of action (I had this confused as well).